# Deference between Service and factory? and where we have to used

Tags: angularjs, service, factory

Many no of times ask the same question for Service and factory? and i have not found any right answer.. so can any one provide the answer for below question :

1. What is difference Service and factory in angularjs ?
2. Where we have to use Service and factory?
3. if you use service than why not factory?
4. if you use factory than why not service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may refer to this posts ,it is very much clear and on the point.

1. [AngularJS: Service vs provider vs factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666048/angularjs-service-vs-provider-vs-factory)